# MATLAB R2018b Semi-transparent scatter plot based on variable

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a 3D scatter plot (scatter3). The figure has multiple scatter3s (there are multiple groups to plot). I want to vary marker opacity in each of the scatters via a discrete variable. How would this be done?

I have tried using the iterative method of plotting each scatter point, but this destroys the figure plot browser (I would like to be able to use this). Also, this is a slow method. I have also tried [UndocumentedMatlab's alpha tutorial] (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient) but this, for some reason, does not create transparent points on my system (MATLAB 2018b).

Here is the code I have tried:

```
%// example data
x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);
y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);

%// plot scatter, get handle
h = scatter(x,y); 
drawnow; %// important

%// get marker handle
hMarkers = h.MarkerHandle; 

%// get current edge and face color
edgeColor = hMarkers.EdgeColorData;
faceColor = hMarkers.FaceColorData;

%// set face color to the same as edge color
faceColor = edgeColor;

%// opacity
opa = 0.3;

%// set marker edge and face color
hMarkers.EdgeColorData = uint8( [edgeColor(1:3); 255*opa] ); 
hMarkers.FaceColorData = uint8( [faceColor(1:3); 255*opa] );
```

This does not produce varied opacity in points.

I would like to vary the opacity of each marker via a separate variable (same length as XYZ).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are varying the color and not opacity. To vary opacity of a scatter plot the easiest way is to use the "Name,Value" pairs as described in Matlab documentation. First thing I would like you to know is that whatever you need to know about Matlab functions can be found by using `doc function_name` or in this case `doc scatter3`.

Say now that you have some points which you stored in variables and you would like to set the opacity of those points. First thing to note is that scatter plots have two opacity parameters. The first opacity parameter varies the opacity of the edge of the marker, while the second varies the opacity of the face of the marker. Now if your markers are not filled the face opacity plays no role. Now say that your markers are filled and that you would like to set both the face and edge opacity to half of maximum, then you would use:

```
scatter3(x_data, y_data, z_data, 'MarkerEdgeAlpha', 0.5, 'MarkerFaceAlpha', 0.5);
```

Now you can naturally exchange the 0.5 with any numeric value between zero and one to obtain the wanted result.

Comment: Hi, I thought I had made it clear that I want to change the opacity of each point individually. This will set a global alpha for the entire scatter3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the style of each individual point, I suggest you plot them one-by-one.

e.g.

```
fig_obj = {};
fig_obj = [fig_obj; scatter(x(1),y(1))];

set(fig_obj, ...)
```

Yes it is slow. But it gets intractable if you try to identify individual points within one graphic object.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. With 2000 points, this makes it basically impossible to edit scatter calls from my multiple calls. However, I think this method coupled with hhgroup will work. Thanks!

Comment: Why not? Computationally, 2000 points is nothing. You have a logic applied to the styling of your individual points, don't you? For example, suppose your alpha value comes from the percentile of vector norms, then you can edit the style accordingly with a loop or `arrayfun`.